# How to install Visual Studio on Raspberry Pi using command in linux?

Tags: raspbian, c#

I am have installed Raspberry Pi on my machine, i want to install VS Code. I am using this special command to do this and its not doing anything as its not recognizing it from the terminal. I need help this mates, please assist me.

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

Message "sudo snap command not found.

Comment: Does this help?  https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-visual-studio-code/

Comment: ok i see, how do i use the key stroke in terminal like | im trying to use shift with | its not showing any ideas?

Comment: You could copy and paste from the web page BUT you need to set the locale, time zone, WiFi country code and keyboard up as they are defaults and may not match your location in the real world.  I normally use `sudo raspi-config` but you may be able to do it from the GUI (do not have one here at the moment). From the main menu - select option 4 and work through all the sub-menu items starting at the top.  The lists take a little while to populate.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than installing Visual Studio Code in Raspberry Pi, I would like to suggest an alternative way for development which I personally find a better workflow.

1. Access Raspberry Pi using ssh.
2. Install and Configure Samba Server in Raspberry Pi.
3. Access the Shared directory (configured in Samba Server), from the File Explorer in Windows.
4. Open the directory from Visual Studio Code in Windows.

[Configure Samba Server in Raspberry Pi](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-samba/)